# Excel VBA code, formula and function, not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel formula I have used:

```
=IFNA(LEFT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH("Target Ship*",Ed!1:1,0),,,"Ed")),
 FIND(" ",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH("Target Ship*",Ed!1:1,0),,,"Ed")))-1),"")
```

I am trying to get it to work in VBA, with a function that pulls the Sheet2 name, but with the code below it throws the error

> "Compile Error: Syntax Error"

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(l + i * 2 - 2, j).Formula = "=IFNA(LEFT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH(""Target Ship*"","&shtName&"!1:1,0),,,""&shtName&"")),FIND("" "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH(""Target Ship*"","&shtName&"!1:1,0),,,""&shtName&"")))-1),"""")"
```

Also to the above my code below is not setting the shtName from the function.

```
shtName = sheetName(2)

Function sheetName(num As Integer) As String
    shtName = Sheets(num).Name
End Function
```

Comment: Double check your quotes. You arent using them right.

Comment: And to be on the safe side always enclose sheet names in single quotes when using them in a range reference.

Comment: @braX explain? If a quote is in the original formula to use in vba i need to double them. To add reference in the VBA formula I need to add quote and the &

Comment: The last sheet name concatenation needs one more quote on each side `...,,,""" & shtName & """)))...`

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried that and it highlights error on "!1:1,0),,,"""
What does putting shtName in single quote?

Comment: See my answer below - if a sheet name can contain spaces, it needs to be in single quotes when used in a formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would favor use of tokens and `Replace()` over a bunch of concatenation:

```
Const FRM = _
  "=IFNA(LEFT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH(""Target Ship*"",'<sht>'!1:1,0),,,""<sht>""))," & _
   "FIND("" "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH(""Target Ship*"",'<sht>'!1:1,0),,,""<sht>"")))-1),"""")"

Dim f as String
f = Replace(FRM, "<sht>", sheetName(2))
f = Replace(f, "<x>", someOtherVariable) 'other substitutions as needed...

Worksheets(1).Cells(l + i * 2 - 2, j).Formula = f
```

Your function is not setting the return value correctly:

```
Function sheetName(num As Integer) As String
    sheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(num).Name '<< sheetName not shtName
                '  ^ be specific about the workbook to look in
End Function
```

If you use `Option Explicit` it will warn you about this type of error since `shtName` is an undeclared variable in this context.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a replace to the text within the first Match arg? at the same time?
Also I added a little because apparently my function is pulling the Sheet2 name

Comment: You can use whatever tokens and replacements you need - it's up to you.